Libreoffice calc 7.4.7.2 (on linux) conditional formatting
I try to implement a conditional format in LibreOffice.

What I want to do:
I want the current date to be highlighted, with the 2 columns right next to the date. I can do that, but, I don't get any further than entering the formula for every day at a time.
I'm sure that this can be done by a script in "Conditional formatting", but I can't find it. Can somebody help me?

=TODAY() maybe?
